# Convert a string "May 23, 24, 25 & 26" into separate DateTimes

Tags: vb.net, loops, datetime

I need to break down a given string into datetime(s). The string uses syntax using commas and an ampersand in a particular way as shown below.

A string `"May 5"` should now be `{5/5/17}`.

`"May 6 & 7"` should be `{5/6/17, 5/7/17}`.

`"May 20, 21 & 22"` should be `{5/20/17, 5/21/17, 5/22/17}`.

`"May 28, 29, 30 & 31"` should be `{5/28/17, 5/29/17, 5/30/17, 5/31/17}`.

Comment: Do you have any example code to show? Attempts you've made?

Comment: You would have to create your own function and you could simply use Regex if the format is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - the code is commented to explain pretty much what everything does. The only issue of course if that the month name should be the first word and the rest should be numeric values (apart from the delimiters of course).

```
Private Function DateStringToList(Dstring As String) As List(Of Date)
    'create a list to add converted dates to
    Dim datelist As New List(Of Date)
    'an array of delimiter characters to use when splitting the input string
    Dim delimiterArray() As Char = {" "c, ","c, "&"c}
    'split the input string into a string array, removing any blank entries
    Dim params() As String = Dstring.Split(delimiterArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    'assign the month name from the beginning of the string to Mnth
    Dim Mnth As String = params(0)
    'iterate through the rest of the split elements
    For i As Integer = 1 To params.GetUpperBound(0)
        'workarounf to get the month number from the name - the day and year values dont matter,
        'but you may need to change the order for your local date handling
        Dim monthNumber = Convert.ToDateTime("01-" + Mnth + "-2000").Month
        'create a new date based on this year, the monthNumber as the each day from the params array
        Dim newdate As New Date(DateTime.Now.Year, monthNumber, params(i))
        'add the date to a list
        datelist.Add(newdate)
    Next
    'Return that list to the calling code
    Return datelist
End Function
```

Comment: If you are already using Convert.ToDateTime, could you just use params(i) instead of 01 and remove monthNumber ?

Comment: Yes, I like this solution, but agree with the above comment. The Dim monthNumber can be outside of the loop, based on question example :)